# how to get the id of the title of the scrollview to rename(title in the app bar)

Tags: android, android-studio, uiscrollview, android-appbarlayout

i want to get the id of the scrollview title so that I can rename it with user input. is there anything I can place in the xml or java to give it some kinda of id that I can reference

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will be useful, if you have a toolbar, try this:

```
TextView toolbarTextView;
for (int i = 0; i < yourToolbar.getChildCount(); ++i) {
    final View toolbarChild = yourToolbar.getChildAt(i);
    if (toolbarChild instanceof TextView) {
        toolbarTextView = (TextView) toolbarChild;
    }
}
```

Or if you have a supportActionBar, try this:

```
final ActionBar myActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
if (myActionBar != null) {
    myActionBar.setTitle("This a new text");
}
```